# how to generalize gray coding

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces, algorithms, coding-theory, gray-code

I have a set of $2^n$ points in $d$-dimensional real space. This is my "constellation" $C \subset  {\mathbb R}^d$. Let $B$ be the set of binary unordered tuples of length $n$. I want find a $1:1$ mapping $g : C \to B$ so that points in $C$ that are closest to each other (using euclidean distance) are mapped to points in $B$ that are closest to each other (using hamming distance). This is a very similar setting to "gray coding" hence the question title; although the problem might show up in different settings : "aligning two metrics" maybe ... or something along these lines.

Comment: You will probably need to specify and formalize what exactly you mean by "*so that points in C that are closest to each other (using euclidean distance) are mapped to points in B that are closest to each other*". Consider for example $d+1=2^n$ and $C$ being the vertices on a $d$-dimensional simplex (and so all the pairwise distances are the same). However, the binary vectors of length $n$ obviously don't all have the same Hamming distance.

Comment: @AndreasLenz the simplex is probably too pathological an example. For one, $|C|$ is not $2^n$. Since $B$ has $n-1$ pairwise distances, I can add an extra constraint on $C$ having at least that many.